# VOIP using XMPP Framework in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xmpp, sip, voip

I am able to implement Facebook and Gmail chat with the help of XMPP Framework in my iPhone app. Wanted to know if its possible to implement VOIP(SIP) in a similar manner using XMPP.

Comment: Can you be able to send images over xmpp framework in iOS?

Answer (score 9):

You can use jingle framework.This is what jingle wiki says:
"Jingle is an extension to the Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) which adds peer-to-peer (P2P) session control (signaling) for multimedia interactions such as in Voice over IP (VoIP) or videoconferencing communications. It was designed by Google and the XMPP Standards Foundation. The multimedia streams are delivered using the Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP). If needed, NAT traversal is assisted using Interactive Connectivity Establishment (ICE)."

The libjingle library, used by Google Talk to implement Jingle, has been released to the public under a BSD license. It implements both the current standard protocol and the older, pre-standard version

Also there is a framework in Google project repository.
http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/

Also, one more link related to this:
[iOS: Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code)

May be this will give you an idea.

Comment: Does it work with iPhone. I didn't find any xcodeproject in the downloaded files

Comment: personally I have not used this framework.But I think this is developed in C++.so you can easily port or use in IPhone.Also, take a look at the code of client/peer_connection_client.cc.May be with a little tweak, you can make it work with IPhone as well.

Comment: Do we need any external server?

Comment: Are you winning to implement XMPP with video calling ??

Comment: is your question about "to develop XMPP with video calling"?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to implement VOIP using XMPP. For ios many are providind SDK's which you can easily implement in your code. Among that one of the best is [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/), which is very useful and easy to implement. Its providing P2P video chat, text chat , group chat and file transfer facilities.

But now WebRTC is gaining much popularity for VOIP purposes.WebRTC (Web Real-Time Communication) is an API definition being drafted by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) to enable browser to browser applications for voice calling, video chat and P2P file sharing without plugins.

[Open Tok](http://tokbox.com/) is a rather useful product which can be used for VOIP calling in ios devices. They are also providing a basic IOS sdk for easy implementation.

Comment: Quickblox is not good as it does not support voip services. In killed state, you can not start the app in background.

Answer (score 1):

checkout these two products:
1- monal:   https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monal/id317711500?mt=8

2- talkonaut: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talkonaut/id375113323?mt=8

they both claim to support jingle